# Would you use a macro or VBA code with MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to Access 2013.  I have a warehouse management project to create with Access - many users at the same time from different locations.

I have a couple of basic questions, if you don't mind.
Is it better to code using only macros or is VBA the preferred choice?  Or is a combination a better approach?  If so, what sort of functions would you code in each modality?

The next question has to do with data entry. We are going to be using bar-code scanners in a few locations.

I would like the terminal or the wireless receiver to be in ready mode all the time for the next scan, which of course happens at random times throughout the day.

I assume I would create a loop that stopped at a point that called for input into a text box.  How would I keep the program 'active' letting the operators just scan without them having to refresh anything.
Hope the questions aren't too vague or elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some additions to what Paulo wrote:

I don't know how many "many users" are, but if it's more than a few, you should think about using Sql Server Express (the free version) as backend instead of an Access file. It is much more robust. And if "different locations" means that WAN connections will be involved, you can get away with much lower bandwidth requirements than with an Access backend.

Don't even think about macros, use VBA. One of many reasons is that you can find lots of help for VBA (here and elsewhere), but not for macros.

AFAIK, bar-code scanners basically behave like a keyboard - they send the text/numbers they scan as if it were entered by hand. If the Textbox has the focus to receive the input, you can react to the AfterUpdate or OnChange event of the Textbox, no need for an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help in giving me a much needed direction.  I am fairly comfortable with VBA so that's an easy decision.  I will explore the Sql Server Express.  'Many' users could be up to 10.  Locations are within the warehouse (120,000 sq ft).  For the bar code input, how do I keep the terminals (Windows 7 and 8) from going to 'sleep' after, say, 20 minutes?

Comment: If it's in the warehouse LAN, this could work with an Access backend, but I would still strongly suggest Sql Server for stability and scaleability. - Sleep: via Control panel -> Power options. :)

Comment: sleep - duh, of course.  Downloading SQL now.  Thanks again.

Comment: :)  BTW, "ExpressAndTools 32BIT\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe" is the version I would recommend.  SQL Server Management Studio is your administration frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

> many users at the same time from different locations

You should create a database-only file for storage and a front-end in another `.accdb` file. That's the best -- or only -- way to get multiple users without problems.

> Is it better to code using only macros or is VBA the preferred choice? Or is a combination a better approach?

I would always go for VBA because of flexibility, but that also requires more knowledge of what you're doing.

> I assume I would create a loop that stopped at a point that called for input into a text box. How would I keep the program 'active' letting the operators just scan without them having to refresh anything.

I'm not sure if that's the best approach in performance, but your idea is somewhat correct. You can use a loop that in the end of every iteration calls `DoEvents` to allow everything else to run. Otherwise your database will simply freeze. I'm not a big fan of that idea, though.

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  I am fairly familiar with VBA, I will be comfortable going in that direction.  I'm excited to learn how to use Access.

Comment: The idea is the same, if you come from Excel, but Access is even more powerful and it's very easy to store data directly via `CurrentDb().OpenRecordSet(tableName)`. Also, forms in Access are easily controllable using VBA functions. If you hide the Ribbon, it even looks like an app.